React Native. iOS/iPad. Detect whether a device has bottom notch (swipe up bar)
If you look at the bottom part of the iPad device and the app, for different models:

iPad Pro (11-inch) 3-rd generation - has a bottom notch



iPad 6-rd generation - doesn't have it


Is there any way of detecting this area? It is needed for Tab Bar styles correction because it looks differently.
(It seems react-native-device-info doesn't have this API)

Can you elaborate on how it looks different? Is it just the height of it is different?

@user18309290, the device with bottom notch has a line on the bottom, and without notch - just nothing on the bottom

import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const { bottom } = useSafeAreaInsets();
const hasBottomNotch = bottom > 0;

For iPad without a bottom notch returns zero.
For iPad with a bottom notch returns more than zero (e.g. 20).
